# Cant set the startup localization for a UE4

Tags: mobile, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

there!

I'm trying to set up the localization for a UE4 game.

I got DefaultGame.ini containing these lines:

```
InternationalizationPreset=All
CulturesToStage=en
-CulturesToStage=en
+CulturesToStage=en
+CulturesToStage=fr
```

What I am getting is "fr" localiztion at startup while I need a "en" one. What is the correct order for adding available localizations in DefaultGame.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
InternationalizationPreset=All
+CulturesToStage=en
+CulturesToStage=fr
```

If that doesn't work try setting

```
InternationalizationPreset=English
```

After this you can goto into Project settings and reset your localization via the menu there to have a properly formatted .INI